# Django default CSS not getting applied to Admin page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to build my first app in Django.

I have done following: Installed Python 3.6, PIP, Django 2.1

Activity:

1. Created a project
2. Started web server using manage.py of a
   project
3. Create a django app in the project folder
4. Edited settings.py to include the app name (folder name) in INSTALLED_APPS list
5. Edited models.py to create a class for my model 6)
6. From CLI created the migrations files
7. Applied the migrations
8. Registered my model with django admin by modifying admin.py
9. Create superuser from CLI
10. Login to locahost:8000/admin

At this stage I am able to login to admin **but the CSS is not getting applied in the Admin webpage**.
[Admin Panel - Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKOTp.jpg)

NOTE: The home page (http://localhost:8000/) of the server is displaying properly with styling [Homepage with proper style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEAof.jpg)
This could be because the CSS is inline within the page. [Homepage CSS inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOByp.jpg)

However the problem is only with Admin page. In admin page, all CSS are being served through seperate CSS file & there is no CSS inline. 
I have checked that the CSS files in the Admin web page source are accessible (able to download / view the CSS scripts). [Admin Panel - CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOdC0.jpg)

Also, I have tried on FF, Chrome, IE.

I also referred to the documentation [Django 2.1 documentation for static file](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/howto/static-files/) & the top two conditions are met for INSTALLED_APPS & STATIC_URL.

Since I am not presenting any specific CSS of my own & these are all default files of Django I am not sure if I should be doing any other changes somewhere?

Comment: What's the status code you receive in your CLI when issued a GET request to CSS files? Look for `GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1` I cannot replicate your issue on my env, this is the first time I have ever seen it occur.

Comment: Hi @sagnik - is it possible to include your `settings.py` file, specifically the parts which relate to serving up static assets.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I have uploaded the settings file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16WQ8Mioon8Ct5DLrkSOa-QLQV3E4TOcD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @saketk21 status_code = 200; I am able to GET all 3 CSS file http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css; 
http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/dashboard.css; 
http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/responsive.css; Somehow the CSS are not getting applied

Comment: Pretty bizarre happening. Can somebody with higher rep start a bounty?

Comment: Updated my question with a note that the issue is only with the admin page of Django